# Extrair informações de um arquivo texto com shell script e expressões regulares

Tags: shell-script

Quero fazer um script com Shell script que extraia de um arquivo de texto emoticons, por exemplo `;)`, `:)`, `:3`, `:(`, `xD` e que também conte os emoticons de cada sentença.
Uma sentença é declarada positiva se a soma dos emoticons positivos exceder 2,5 vezes a soma dos emoticons negativos se presentes, eu fiz esse código que conta a quantidade de positivo, por favor como eu terminaria esse script?

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
file="${1}"

while IFS= read -r line
x=0
do
    let "x=x+1"

    qtd=$(echo "$line" | sed -r 's/ /\n/g' | grep "POSITIVO" | wc -l)
    echo "SENTENÇA $x \t - POSITIVO - $qtd"
done <"$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi completamente o pedido...

No exemplo abaixo calcula-se a polaridade de um ficheiro.

Na realidade isto é bash mas com pequenas alterações deve funciona como ksh...

```
#!/bin/bash
pos=$(grep -oP ':\)|;\)|:D' $1 | wc -l)     ## juntar outros positivos
neg=$(grep -oP ':\('        $1 | wc -l)     ## juntar outros negativos

if (( $pos * 2 > $neg * 5 )) ;then
   echo "Positivo "
else
   echo "Negativo"
fi
```

**UPDATE**: para dar a polaridade de cada linha podemos por exemplo juntar com a versão proposta pelo PO:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  pos=$(<<<$line grep -oP ':\)|;\)|:D' | wc -l)   ## juntar outros positivos
  neg=$(<<<$line grep -oP ':\('        | wc -l)   ## juntar outros negativos

  echo $line $pos $neg
  if (( $pos * 2 > $neg * 5 )) ;then
     echo "Positivo "
  else
     echo "Negativo"
  fi

done <"$1"
```

Comment: Quase isso, eu só queria que estivesse um loop que lesse linha por linha de um arquivo de texto, e identificasse se essa frase é positiva ou negativa.